# jQuery Hide/Show issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function unhide(divID) {
        var item = document.getElementById(divID);
        if (item) {
            item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this code. It toggles hide/unhide for all browsers except IE. The direct site is http://lilacparadise.x10.mx/comics/. I'm helping a friend out but I have little experience with javascript. Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this code?

Comment: That's not jQuery, it's [Vanilla.js](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Comment: this is not jquery, this is native js.

Comment: Alright thanks lol shows how inexperienced I am. Could you help me anyhow?

Comment: Could you put more context directly in your question rather than (or as well as) linking to another site? How do you call the function? @JaredFarrish - Love the Vanilla.js site.

Comment: On line `6` of the source, you've got a `$.click()` handler (which *is* jQuery) that looks like the jQuery version of what you have above. That checks for `:hidden` and then manually calls `$.toggle()`? You realize that's the entire point of `$.toggle()`, to go back and forth?

Comment: Believe me I would but I don't have much experience to this language. That's why I'm so vague. That's my knowledge. I would like some direction so I can learn it.

Comment: The page you linked to seems to _call_ the `unhide()` function but not _define_ it - the code you show in your question needs to be included in your page too. Also, where you have something like `onClick="javascript:unhide('parasitef');javascript:unhide('parasitel');javascript:unhide('parasitea');"` you should remove all of the `javascript:` labels.

Comment: Nevermind, you're calling them together (which is a good). Only nowhere on that page do I see your code? Also, this is wrong: `<td class="title" class="togglediv">` Both of those class names should be in the same `class` attribute.

Comment: Thank you sooo much @JaredFarrish , I didn't write this code. my friend did. He's throwing me a few bucks to look at it but with the Javascript I'm a tad lost. Your advice is helping a lot. I'm going to try that. And yeah I noticed that about the classes .. was about to fix but wanted to know if the language I can't read is OK

Comment: @JaredFarrish Did all of the above but still not working in IE :(

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% sure about your question. Instead of function i would suggent you to use toggle in jquery.remaining jquery will take care.

css part.

```
.hidden
{
display:none
}

.visi
{
display:block
}
```

jquery part.

```
$("#divid").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
    });
})
```

hope this will be helpfull

Comment: Please chk the link in IE. if its wrking then some up worng in your code. its working for me in IE.  [http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had a computer problem and had to restart.

First, if you have access to the page itself, *get rid of this line*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
```

And replace it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

That version of jQuery was released in January, 2009. That's ancient, and it's time to get rid of it. The [`$.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) method I use below was introduced in 1.4.4.

You should be able to figure out what I've done below. Let me know if you have any questions. It's *not* drag and drop. There's also more CSS in the fiddle demo below, but I've only included the parts relevant to the demo.

```
$(function load(){
    var $my = $('#my'),
        $comment = $my.find('.comment'),
        $siblings = $my.find('.siblings');

    $my.click(function toggle(){
        $comment.text($siblings.not(':hidden').text());

        $siblings.toggleClass('green').fadeToggle();
    });
});​
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ULDKg/**](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/yfJRN/)

This is the CSS and markup it's working with:

```
.siblings.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.siblings.green {
    background: green;
}

<div id="my">
    <div class="comment">Click for the comment...</div>
    <div class="siblings green">I don't know...</div>
    <div class="siblings hidden">What is it?</div>
</div>​
```

I've tested in Firefox, Chrome, and IE 7-9 and it works fine. But you need v1.4.4 or higher at least.

Also note that this uses the [short form of `$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). This means that it waits until the page has been parsed and the DOM is ready to be accessed (in it's entirety). You can use `$(window).load()` instead, it would work, but what you see here mimics what's already been done (which is ok). Just keep it in mind you *need* it to wait until the page has been parsed at least, or the code sans either wrapper method needs to *follow* the elements it's accessing in where it's included.

Comment: `$my` points to the `<div id="my"` and [`$.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) searches *within* that element for the selector you're using, not the entire document.

Comment: OK.. The issue with your's is the fact the buttons are disappearing. I need the buttons to remain, the list to fly out

Comment: Then tweak it. It can't be that hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

`className` may not work properly in IE.  Can you try this and let me know whether it works,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function unhide(divID) {
        var item = document.getElementById(divID);
        if (item) {
           if(item.getAttribute('class')=='hidden'){
               item.setAttribute('className', "unhidden") || item.setAttribute('class', "unhidden");
           }else{
               item.setAttribute('className', "hidden") || item.setAttribute('class', "hidden");
           }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Everything but internet explorer :(